# iOS network activity indicator with progress HUD

Tags: ios

I'm using MBProgressHUD in my app to make it more clear to the user when the app is waiting for the network.

My app is littered with calls to MBProgressHUD.

Example:

```
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [User findBy:@{@"email": email} success:^(NSDictionary *user) {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

So every network call is wrapped in an MBprogress show and then hide. There's gotta be a cleaner way.

I'd like to do this on a global level so that when there's network activity then the HUD comes on, when it stops then the HUD turns off.

How can I make the HUD mimic what the iPhone network activity indicator is doing?

I didn't see any API for this.

Note: I'm using AFNetworking 2.0

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple.

1. You need to locate the "Top" most method that all or most of the requests use (Probably in the your implementation of `AFnetworking` request.
2. Use the app window to present the hud so you can present it from you `AFNetworking` class. Simply add this 2 methods to your class -

   ```
     + (MBProgressHUD *)showNetworkHUDWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
         UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
         [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:window animated:YES];
          MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];
          hud.labelText = title;
          return hud;
     }

      + (void)dismissNetworkHUD {
           UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
          [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:window animated:YES];
        }
   ```

you can also check one of MBProgressHUD "show while" methods -

-(id)showAnimated:(BOOL)animated whileExecutingBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block;

```
- (void)showAnimated:(BOOL)animated whileExecutingBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block completionBlock:(MBProgressHUDCompletionBlock)completion;

- (void)showAnimated:(BOOL)animated whileExecutingBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block onQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue;

- (void)showAnimated:(BOOL)animated whileExecutingBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block onQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue
          completionBlock:(MBProgressHUDCompletionBlock)completion;
```

this way the hud will disappear at the end of the execution.

Comment: I've moved the calls to the models using your global code. This is better, but ideally I'd like to have mbprogress hud code just set once. Not set in every model network method. I could create a parent network class for the models to inherit from and then call mbprogress from there, but I don't have a way to know when to turn off mbprogress. ie: there is no delegate callback from AFNetworking that I can see. I could chain 3 success/failure block calls together,eg: NetworkObject -> ModelObject -> ControllerObject and that way could get the callback to turn off MBBprogress, but that seems messy.